# stdout/stderr tuples or string output

Tags: python, tuples

I have some code, it's a standard command to stdout.

```
params = [toolsDir + "\\adb.exe", "shell", "pm", "path", app]
p = Popen(params, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    if "package:" in stdout:
         package = stdout[8:].rstrip()
```

Line 3, returns a string, as Line 5 then works successfully without error, I can split and rstrip() on 'package'.

```
 stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

However... if I remove 'stderr' from Line 3, so it ends up as

```
stdout = p.communicate()
```

I get the error:

```
    package = stdout[8:].rstrip()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Can someone explain why this happens, as stderr isn't even being defined to a pipe on Line 2 Popen, so why does it return a tuple without stderr, but a string with it?

I have already fixed this problem, albeit, it took me a good 30 minutes, and now wish to know why it matters.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) returns a tuple

So you can either unpack it on-the-fly (like in your first version):

```
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

or you can get the tuple as-is (like is your modified code):

```
stdout = p.communicate() # tuple with 'stdout' and 'stderr'
```

I you want to drop `stderr`, you can write:

```
stdout = p.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This simpler example could help you understand what is going on:

```
>>> a, b = (1,2)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

If `b` is removed, then:

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> a
(1, 2)
```

`a` is assigned the value of the whole tuple, which is not what you want.